# Java 8 Streams hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I need perform an hashmap iteration using Java 8 streams. I need to iterate over an hashmap. Check whether a particular key ("new") does not have null or empty values, copy that value to a variable (String val1) of type string. Then again check for another key for ex:"old" and then copy that value to a variable (String val2) of type string and call the main method where i need to send these 2 values (val1, val2). This has to be done with in hashmap iteration. Can you please help me on this.

The code:

```
map1.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(s -> { 
        if (s.getKey().contains("abc") && !s.getValue().equals("") && s.getValue()!=null) {
            String val1 = s.getValue;
            if (s.getKey().contains("bb")) {
                String val2 = s.getValue(); //call the function
                callFunction(val1,val2);
            }
        }
        else {
        } 
    });
```

Comment: Sounds like homework which should be done by your own

Comment: Indeed. What I do not understand is what is the point of posting on SO when the first match of a google search give an appropriate answer.

Comment: Hello Renuka, can you post some your effort(try google with "java 8 streams hashmap iterators").

Comment: I know there is some mistake in this snippet, but here is what i am looking for                   map1.entrySet().stream().filter(s->{
     
     if(s.getKey().contains("abc")&&!s.getValue().equals("")&& s.getValue()!=null) {
      
      String val1 = s.getValue;
      
      if(s.getKey().contains("bb")) {
       String val2 = s.getValue();
       
       //call the function
       
       callFunction(val1,val2);
       
      }
      
      
      
     }else {
      
     }
    });

Comment: Post your code in the question and format it. It's hard to read code in comments.

Comment: What is happening after `filter` operation on the stream?

Comment: From Java SE API javadocs: [Streams are functional in nature...](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description).

Comment: for(Map.Entry e : map1.entrySet()) {
if(e.containsKey("new")&& !e.getValue().equals("")){
  String val1 = (String) e.getValue();
      if(e.containsKey("old")&& !e.getValue().equals("")){
  String val2 = (String) e.getValue();
 //call the function-- This is boolean
  if(validateMethod(val1, val2)){ // if true
  Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
  map2.putAll(e);
 }}
 }
    }          This needs to be done using java 8

Comment: You may want to try some _simple_ examples using streams like [these examples](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/10/java-8-stream-tutorial/).. Then apply those to arrive at your problem's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Need to be done using Java 8

```
for(Map.Entry e : map1.entrySet()) {
                if(e.containsKey("new")&& !e.getValue().equals("")){
                    String val1 = (String) e.getValue();

                    if(e.containsKey("old")&& !e.getValue().equals("")){
                        String val2 = (String) e.getValue();

                        //call the function-- This is boolean
                        if(validateMethod(val1, val2)){ // if true
                            Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();

                            map2.putAll(e);

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your code does nothing, because `map2` is never used, so it's not accessible after the if and the for

Comment: And containsKey is not a method of Map.Entry

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for particular keys : `new` and `old` so you don't need to iterate over the entries of the map, because if the keys exist they will be unique.

- get the value of the specific keys, if they don't exist, keep en empty `String`
- do your stuff with these values

```
Map<String, String> map1 = ...;
String v1 = map1.getOrDefault("new", "");
String v2 = map1.getOrDefault("old", "");
Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
if(!v1.isEmpty() && !v2.isEmpty() && validateMethod(v1, v2)){    
    // do your stuff
}
```

*You might put the check for isEmpty in your `validateMethod` rather than in an if*

Answer (score -3):

Try it with this:

```
yourMap.entrySet().stream()
```

From this point, you can manage. Stream consists of `Entry<Key,Value>` so you can check whatever you want to.

Comment: This does not answer the question, and if it does, you can bet this answer exists already, in which case you should flag as a duplicate.